The swaggerUI doesn't show a button to upload a file, only a textbox
Existing view of api
I replaced @RequestParam(“file”) with @RequestPart(“file”) still doesn't work. application.yaml file I also added the configuration, or not, please masters to help me this poor child!Thank you all.wwwwwwww

This code will fulfil your requirements
@Operation(summary = "uploadFile")
    @PostMapping(value = "/uploadFile", consumes = {MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE})
    public void uploadFiles(@RequestPart("file") final MultipartFile file, @RequestParam("fileDto") String dto) {
    }


consumes = {MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE} shows that this request accepts multipart media as input
Note: I have remove @Paramters because generally we use this annotation in Get api not with the Post
this will be the v3/api-docs JSON view
"/v1/uploadFile": {
      "post": {     
        "summary": "uploadFile",
        "operationId": "uploadFiles",
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "fileDto",
            "in": "query",
            "description": "fileDto",
            "required": true,
            "schema": {
              "type": "string"
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "file",
            "in": "query",
            "description": "file1"
          }
        ],
        "requestBody": {
          "content": {
            "multipart/form-data": {
              "schema": {
                "required": [
                  "file"
                ],
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                  "file": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "description": "file1",
                    "format": "binary"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }

